# Can't get my input to center

Tags: php, html, css

I have the following bit of code, where all the input elements are supposed to be centered (with respect to the div in which they reside).

```
    <div>
        <h3 style="text-align: center">Type in the text you see below.</h3>
        <center>
            <img src="image<?php echo $_SESSION['count'] ?>.png" id="capimg" style="border: 0px">
        </center>
        <form action=" <?php echo $_SERVER['PHP_SELF']; ?>" method="POST"/ >
        <center><input type="text" name="input" id="sentipt" style="width: 300px;"/></center>
        <center><input type="hidden" name="flag" value="1" class="sentipt"/></center>
        <center><input type="submit" value="submit" name="submit" class="sentipt"/></center>
        </form>


        <form action=" <?php echo $_SERVER['PHP_SELF']; ?>" method="POST">
            <input type="submit" value="refresh the page" class="sentipt"/>
        </form>
    </div>
```

However, the third one, `<center><input type="submit" value="submit" name="submit" class="sentipt"/></center>`, is not centered properly.

**EDIT: Sorry. I figured out the issue. Thanks for the info. I'll choose a best answer.**

Comment: Don't use the center tag. Use CSS for styling. Also, you should be using external stylesheets instead of inline styling. You should be able to use the margin: 0 auto trick in your stylesheet to center these things.

Comment: Do as you did for your first button `<center><input type="submit" value="submit" name="submit" class="sentipt"/></center>` or just `<div align="center">`

Comment: `<center>` is deprecated. you should not be using it in html anymore.

Comment: @Fred-ii-: `align="..."` is not valid on divs.

Comment: @MarcB My head's spinning as to what we're supposed to "now" use. Years ago they tell us `<p align...>` `<center>` then `<div align...>` who comes up with these changes? I say leave well enough alone. Is the WWW consortium forcing us to align by means of CSS exclusively?

Comment: not forcing, but they are divorcing "presentation" from "content". if it wasn't for css, you'd still be littering your html with `<font>` tags, so be thankful for that.

Comment: Yes I agree on the `<font>` tag, however having to gain control over every element is getting a bit too complicated, especially when it comes to alignment. My take on it is, since the coming of mobiles/iPad etc., and the ever decreasing use of PC's, they're probably trying to set a new standard that will be compatible with every device; "*compatible; right*". It just seems to be a constant struggle having to design a Website that will show up (*or try to*) properly as the way it was intended to look like. @MarcB

Comment: @Fred-ii- [Why Use CSS](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/CSS/Getting_started/Why_use_CSS).

Just read the 3 points thats all ~

CSS avoids duplication (How about using a single center tag to center stuff all over your page? a css class does much more than that).
Makes maintenance easier (Well if you are the only human being that'll ever see and have to deal with your markup then ignore this).
and most of all, lets us 'Use the same content with different styles for different purposes' well how about doing so with the plain old tags..?

Comment: @TJ I agree and it's a good page thanks. Yet, I seem to having to be struggling at times in trying to center certain elements with CSS and it's never the same fight neither. Whereas in the past, one would just do "here, center this; done". But CSS isn't really all it's cracked up to be. It's very good, but not as simple as some think it to be.

Comment: Give `display: inline-block;` to input and then say its parent to `text-align: center;`.

Answer (score 0):

Do as you did for your first button `<center><input type="submit" value="submit" name="submit" class="sentipt"/></center>`

You can try

```
<div align="center"><input type="submit" value="submit" name="submit" class="sentipt"/></div>
```

or

```
<div style="text-align:center;"><input type="submit" value="submit" name="submit" class="sentipt"/></div>
```